# Why there is a restriction for explicit casting a generic to a class type but there is no restriction for casting a generic to an interface type?

Tags: c#, generics

While reading Microsoft documentation, I stumbled on such an interesting code sample:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{...}
class SomeClass
{...}
class MyClass<T> 
{
   void SomeMethod(T t)
   {
      ISomeInterface obj1 = (ISomeInterface)t;//Compiles
      SomeClass      obj2 = (SomeClass)t;     //Does not compile
   }
}
```

It means you can cast your generic to the interface explicitly but not to the class unless you have a constraint. Well, I still cannot understand the logic behind the decision as both interface and class type castings are throwing exceptions, so why would one protect against only one of these exceptions?

BTW- there is a way around the compile error but this does not remove the logic mess in my head:

```
class MyOtherClass
{...}

class MyClass<T> 
{

   void SomeMethod(T t)

   {
      object temp = t;
      MyOtherClass obj = (MyOtherClass)temp;

   }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity: can you type "SomeClass obj2 = (SomeClass)(object)t;"?

Comment: yes, this is done by the second snippet

Comment: Check this http://philipm.at/2011/1014/, found it when trying to find the explanation. Spoiler alert - might confuse you more!;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's exactly what you get in normal circumstances - without generics - when you try to cast between classes with no inheritance relationship:

```
 public interface IA
 {
 }

 public class B
 {
 }

 public class C
 {
 }

 public void SomeMethod( B b )
 {
     IA o1 = (IA) b;   <-- will compile
     C o2 = (C)b;  <-- won't compile
 }
```

So without a constraint, the generic class will behave as if there is no relationship between the classes.

**Continued...**

Well, let's say someone does this:

```
 public class D : B, IA
 {
 }
```

And then calls:

```
SomeMethod( new D() );
```

Now you'll see why the compiler lets the interface cast pass. It really can't know at compile time if an interface is implemented or not.

Remember that the D class may very well be written by someone who is using your assembly - years after you compiled it. So there is no chance that the compiler can refuse to compile it. It must be checked at run time.

Comment: nice point but it still confusing why they chose to allow one cast and disallow the second?

Comment: Updated my answer to include that.

Comment: If you tried `D o3 = (D)b;` in `SomeMethod(B b)` would that compile? It strikes me that the same argument applies that what you pass in might be a descendant that is valid for the cast but might not be... (and yes, I'm being lazy and not just trying it myself at the moment).

Comment: Yes, lazy @Chris ;-) that would compile.

Comment: "It really can't know at compile time if an interface is implemented or not." - why? It has all the info necessary to make the conclusion, cannot get the "years ago" argument too. The compiler would refuse to compile your new library, not the old one

Comment: @Hohhi unless your `T` class is `sealed`, there is no way for compiler to be sure if passed object doesn't implement some interface or not. See full example in my answer.

Comment: @Hohhi why on earth would the compiler stop anyone from passing D - which derives from B - to a public method expecting a B ???????????

Comment: @Hohhi ...or maybe I don't understand what you mean. However I can't understand how it would work without the compiler examining the *code* inside "SomeMethod" if "SomeMethod" is located in a different assembly. And then consider the fact that "SomeMethod" could be, say, in a WebService, and all the compiler have is "void SomeMethod( B b )". How can the compiler know if "SomeMethod" makes any assumptions about "b" also expects an interface to be implemented or not.

Answer (score 2):

The big difference is that an interface is guaranteed to be a reference type.  Value types are the trouble makers.  It is explicitly mentioned in the C# Language Specification, chapter 6.2.6, with an excellent example that demonstrates the problem:

---

The above rules do not permit a direct explicit conversion from an unconstrained type parameter to a non-interface type, which might be surprising. The reason for this rule is to prevent confusion and make the semantics of such conversions clear. For example, consider the following declaration:

```
class X<T>
{
    public static long F(T t) {
        return (long)t;             // Error 
    }
}
```

If the direct explicit conversion of t to int were permitted, one might easily expect that X.F(7) would return 7L. However, it would not, because the standard numeric conversions are only considered when the types are known to be numeric at compile time. In order to make the semantics clear, the above example must instead be written:

```
class X<T>
{
    public static long F(T t) {
        return (long)(object)t;     // Ok, but will only work when T is long
    }
}
```

This code will now compile but executing X.F(7) would then throw an exception at runtime, since a boxed int cannot be converted directly to a long.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing wrong with it. The only difference is that, in first case, compiler can detect *at compile time* that where is no possible cast, but he can't be so "sure" about interfaces, so error, in this case, will rise only at runtime. So,

```
// Compiles
ISomeInterface obj1 = (ISomeInterface)t;

// Сompiles too!
SomeClass obj2 = (SomeClass)(object)t;
```

will produce same errors at runtime.

So the reason can be: compiler doesn't know which interfaces class implements, but it knows classes inheritance (hence `(SomeClass)(object)t` method works). In other words: invalid casting is forbidden in CLR, the only difference is that in some cases it can be detected at compile time, and in some - can't. The main reason behind that, even if compiler knows about all class' interfaces, it doesn't know about it's descendants, which can implement it, and are valid for being `T`. Consider following scenario:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MyClass<SomeClass> mc = new MyClass<SomeClass>();

            mc.SomeMethod(new SomeClassNested());

        }
    }

    public interface ISomeInterface
    {
    }

    public class SomeClass
    {

    }

    public class SomeClassNested : SomeClass, ISomeInterface
    {

    }

    public class MyClass<T>
    {
        public void SomeMethod(T t)
        {
            // Compiles, no errors at runtime
            ISomeInterface obj1 = (ISomeInterface)t;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do you think he doesn't know? everything is written in the assembly in the metadata tables.

Comment: @Karel well, everything is in assembly, that's for sure, but that doesn't mean that compiler knows it. Compiler is relatively "dumb" thing.

Comment: Can you link some reference to compilers not being able to find out what interfaces a class implements? It sounds wrong to me but I am open to education on the subject.

Comment: @PetrAbdulin: Ah, I think I see what you mean now, yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference between casting to an interface and casting
to an class lies in the fact that c# supports multiple "inheritance"
only for interfaces. What does that mean? The compiler is only able to 
determine at compile time whether or not a cast is valid for a class
because C# does not allow multiple inheritance for classes.

On the other hand the compiler does not know at compile time whether or
not your class implements the interface used in the cast. Why?
Someone could inherit from your class and implement the interface
used in your cast. So, the compiler is not aware of this at compile time.
(See `SomeMethod4()` below).

However the compiler is able to determine whether or not
a cast to an interface is valid, if your class is sealed.

Consider the following example:

```
interface ISomeInterface
{}
class SomeClass
{}

sealed class SealedClass
{
}

class OtherClass
{
}

class DerivedClass : SomeClass, ISomeInterface
{
}

class MyClass
{
  void OtherMethod(SomeClass s)
  {
    ISomeInterface t = (ISomeInterface)s; // Compiles!
  }

  void OtherMethod2(SealedClass sc)
  {
    ISomeInterface t = (ISomeInterface)sc; // Does not compile!
  }

  void OtherMethod3(SomeClass c)
  {
    OtherClass oc = (OtherClass)c; // Does not compile because compiler knows 
  }                                // that SomeClass does not inherit from OtherClass!

  void OtherMethod4()
  {
    OtherMethod(new DerivedClass()); // In this case the cast to ISomeInterface inside
  }                                  // the OtherMethod is valid!
}
```

The same is true for generics.

Hope, this helps.